# android WebView won't work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I'm little bit struggle when i load the YouTube video url in a android webview. I load the embed code of that particular YouTube video link into the webview. I successfully loaded. Here my problem is, i must load more than 10 links, so i used scrollview (i used listview also) to show the loaded links. when i scroll the layout it placed over the header layout and also it's not loaded properly. Here i post my code with my output screenshot any one please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

**main.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/header_layout" />

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" >

            <!-- <ImageView -->
            <!-- android:id="@+id/inner_image" -->
            <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
            <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
            <!-- android:layout_below="@+id/inner_image" -->
            <!-- android:background="@drawable/lyrics_inner" /> -->

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/web" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/web1" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/web2" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/web3" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**header_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header_backButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#333322"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="HOME"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    />
```

**YoutubeActivity.java**

```
package com.devappandroid.youtube;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class YoutubeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private String src_value = "http://www.youtube.com/v/9WFvopZMty4?version=3&feature=player_embedded";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        WebView myWebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
        WebView myWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web2);
        WebView myWebView3 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web3);
        WebView myWebView4 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web4);
        myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        myWebView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView1.getSettings()
                .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        myWebView1.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        myWebView1.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        myWebView1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        myWebView1.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        myWebView1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        myWebView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView2.getSettings()
                .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        myWebView2.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        myWebView2.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        myWebView2.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        myWebView2.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        myWebView2.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        myWebView3.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView3.getSettings()
                .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        myWebView3.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        myWebView3.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        myWebView3.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        myWebView3.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        myWebView3.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        myWebView4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView4.getSettings()
                .setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        myWebView4.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        myWebView4.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        myWebView4.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        myWebView4.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        myWebView4.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        String newPlay = "<object  style=\"height: 250px; width: 250px\"><param name=\"movie\" value="
                + src_value
                + "\"><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\"><embed src="
                + src_value
                + " type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" allowScriptAccess=\"always\" width=\"360\" height=\"360\"></object >";
        myWebView.loadData(newPlay, "text/html", "utf-8");
        myWebView1.loadData(newPlay, "text/html", "utf-8");
        myWebView2.loadData(newPlay, "text/html", "utf-8");
        myWebView3.loadData(newPlay, "text/html", "utf-8");
        myWebView4.loadData(newPlay, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
}
```

output screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

instead RelativeLayout use LinearLayout (vertical view).

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/header_backButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:background="#333322"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="HOME"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    />

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/web" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/web1" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/web2" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/web3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately it won't work it remaing same

Comment: still the same, or something else